# How to Mount Disk for Google Cloud Compute Engine to use with /home?

Tags: centos, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

I have a VM Instance with a small 10GB boot disk running CentOS 7 and would like to mount a larger 200GB Persistent Disk to contain data relating to the /home directory from a previous dedicated server (likely via scp).
Here's what I tried:

**Attempt #1, Symlinks** Might work, but some questions.

- mounted the disk to /mnt/disks/my-persistent-disk
- created folders on the persistent disk that mirror the folders in the old server's /home directory.
- created a symlink in the /home directory for each folder, pointing to the persistent disk.
- scp from old server to the VM /home/example_account for the first account.  Realized scp does not follow symlinks (oops) and therefore the files went to the boot drive instead of the disk.
- I suppose I could scp to /mnt/disks/my-persistent-disk and manage the symlinks and folders.  Would this pose a problem?  Would making an image of the VM with this configuration carry over to new instances (with autoscaling etc)?

**Attempt #2, Mounting into /home**.
Looking for a more 'natural' configuration that works with ftp, scp etc, I mounted the disk in /home/example_account

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /home/example_account
$ sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/sdc /home/example_account
$ sudo chmod a+w /home/example_account
#set the UUID for mounting at startup
$ sudo blkid /dev/sdc
$ sudo nano /etc/fstab
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   10G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0   10G  0 part /
sdc      8:32   0  200G  0 disk /home/example_account
```

- scp from old server to the VM in the /home/example_account works fine. Yay.  However, I would like to have more than just 1 folder in the /home directory.  I suppose I could partition the disk but this feels a bit cumbersome and I'm not exactly sure how many accounts I will use in the future.

---

**Attempt #3, Mount as /home**
I felt the best solution was to have the persistent disk mount as the /home directory.  This would allow for easily adding new accounts within /home without symlinks or disk partitions.

- Attempted to move /home directory to /home.old but realized the Google Cloud Compute Engine would not allow it since I was logged into the system.
- Changed to root user, but still said myusername@instance was logged in and using the /home directory.  As root, I issued pkill -KILL -u myusername and the SSH terminated - apparently how the Google Cloud Compute Engine works with their SSH windows.
- As I cannot change the /home directory, this method does not seem viable unless there is a workaround.

My thoughts:
Ideally, I think #3 is the best solution but perhaps there is something I'm missing (#4 solution) or one of the above situations is the preferable idea but perhaps with better execution.

My question:
In short, how to I move an old server's data to a Google Cloud VM with a persistent disk?

Comment: Hmmm, any thoughts?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? If yes, you can post a self-answer which will help other users with the similar issue. If not, can you provide more details on what you are trying to accomplish e.g. are you trying to mount your local disk to GCE instance under /home directory ? You can choose any of the methods described on [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files) to copy files over to GCE VM.